# Unzip files downloaded from server

Tags: blackberry-10

Hi I am developing an application to download an attachment from server and read those files using Blackberry 10 Cascades(QNX Momentics IDE) . I have downloaded the attachment but the attachment is a .Zip file. How can I unzip the folder? Does anyone have samples please share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use quazip library for unzipping the archive, here quazip porting for Blackberry 10 cascades
https://github.com/hakimrie/quazip

here sample function to unzip a file using quazip to extract a file into /data/ folder

```
bool ZipUtils::extractArchive(QString m_filename) {
// check if file exists
QFile file(m_filename);
if (!file.exists()){
    qDebug() << "file is not exists gan";
    return false;
}

bool result = true;
QuaZip *m_zip = new QuaZip(m_filename);

QString dataFolder = QDir::homePath();
QString bookname = m_filename.split("/").last().split(".").first();

QString dest = dataFolder + "/" + bookname;
QDir dir(dest);
if (!dir.exists()) {
    // create destination folder
    dir.mkpath(".");
}

qDebug() << "destination folder: " + dest;

m_zip->open(QuaZip::mdUnzip);

if (!m_zip) {
    return false;
}
QuaZipFile *currentFile = new QuaZipFile(m_zip);
int entries = m_zip->getEntriesCount();
int current = 0;
for (bool more = m_zip->goToFirstFile(); more; more =
        m_zip->goToNextFile()) {
    ++current;
    // if the entry is a path ignore it. Path existence is ensured separately.
    if (m_zip->getCurrentFileName().split("/").last() == "")
        continue;

    QString outfilename = dest + "/" + m_zip->getCurrentFileName();
    QFile outputFile(outfilename);
    // make sure the output path exists
    if (!QDir().mkpath(QFileInfo(outfilename).absolutePath())) {
        result = false;
        //emit logItem(tr("Creating output path failed"), LOGERROR);
        qDebug() << "[ZipUtil] creating output path failed for:"
                << outfilename;
        break;
    }
    if (!outputFile.open(QFile::WriteOnly)) {
        result = false;
        //emit logItem(tr("Creating output file failed"), LOGERROR);
        qDebug() << "[ZipUtil] creating output file failed:" << outfilename;
        break;
    }
    currentFile->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    outputFile.write(currentFile->readAll());
    if (currentFile->getZipError() != UNZ_OK) {
        result = false;
        //emit logItem(tr("Error during Zip operation"), LOGERROR);
        qDebug() << "[ZipUtil] QuaZip error:" << currentFile->getZipError()
                << "on file" << currentFile->getFileName();
        break;
    }
    currentFile->close();
    outputFile.close();

    //emit logProgress(current, entries);
}

return result;
```

}

please make sure to update your pro file to include quazip library (assume your project & quazip project in the same workspace/folder):

```
INCLUDEPATH += ../src  ../../quazip/src/
SOURCES += ../src/*.cpp
HEADERS += ../src/*.hpp ../src/*.h
LIBS += -lbbsystem
LIBS   += -lbbdata
LIBS += -lz

lupdate_inclusion {
    SOURCES += ../assets/*.qml
}

device {
CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
    DESTDIR = o.le-v7
    LIBS += -Bstatic -L../../quazip/arm/o.le-v7 -lquazip -Bdynamic
}
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    DESTDIR = o.le-v7-g
    LIBS += -Bstatic -L../../quazip/arm/o.le-v7-g -lquazip -Bdynamic    
}
}

simulator {
CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
    DESTDIR = o
    LIBS += -Bstatic -L../../quazip/x86/o-g/ -lquazip -Bdynamic     
}
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    DESTDIR = o-g
    LIBS += -Bstatic -L../../quazip/x86/o-g/ -lquazip -Bdynamic
}
}
```

Comment: how to add this quazip library into my project

Comment: make sure you put quazip project in the same workspace (ie. folder) with your app project, than edit your application.pro file like this:

INCLUDEPATH += ../src  ../../quazip/src/
LIBS += -lz   // since quazip depend on zlib

//update your device & simulator build setting like this:
device {
 CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
  DESTDIR = o.le-v7
  LIBS += -Bstatic -L../../quazip/arm/o.le-v7 -lquazip -Bdynamic
 }
 CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
  DESTDIR = o.le-v7-g
  LIBS += -Bstatic -L../../quazip/arm/o.le-v7-g -lquazip -Bdynamic 
 }
}

Comment: please check my answer, it has been updated with sample pro file.

Answer (score 2):

I used the PKZIP 2.0 compatible archive handler from the [OSDaB Project](http://osdab.42cows.org/snippets/zip.php?mode=advanced), it does the job quite nicely. They provide Zip and UnZip classes. You also need to include linkage to the installed compression library by adding `-lz` to the LIBS variable in your .pro file:

```
LIBS += -lz
```

Sample code:

```
        UnZip unzip;
        UnZip::ErrorCode ec = unzip.openArchive(fileName);
        if (ec != UnZip::Ok) {
            emit errorString(fileName + " could not open archive.");
        } else {
            QList<UnZip::ZipEntry> fileNames = unzip.entryList();

            ec = unzip.extractAll(dirName);
            if (ec != UnZip::Ok) {
                emit errorString(
                        newFileName + " could not extract data to "
                                + dirName);
            } else {
                UnZip::ZipEntry file;
                foreach(file, fileNames) {
                    // do something with file if needed.
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Download the source files and copy them into your project, or build them into a library. You can then use the sample code from their website. I will paste another example into my answer.

Comment: i mean how can i add library into my project.

Comment: That is described in this article: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Cascades-Development/Library-projects-in-Cascades/m-p/1891995#M2899 and in the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373269/add-library-into-cascades