# Add library into cascades

Tags: blackberry-10

Hi I am developing an application to unzip files in blackberry10. For unzipping files I am using quazip library code I get from github. But I dont know how to add this library to my project can anybody please let me know how to add library to blackbery cascades.

Answer (score 2):

To add a library to your BlackBerry 10 project in Momentics you just need to right click on the project and go to Configure->Add Library...

This will start the Add Library wizard where you can specify the path to your library. Just remember to update your `.pro` file. Instructions for doing this are in the wizard. If you're dynamically linking it you'll also need to update your `bar-descriptor.xml` so that the library is packaged in your BAR file as an asset.

Answer (score -1):

I have successful experience in using quazip library in my project. Here are the steps you need to follow in order to get it working in your app:

**1.** Download a copy of zip archive from [QuaZip home page](http://quazip.sourceforge.net/)

**2.** Copy the following files across into your project source folder:

```
qioapi.cpp
quazip.cpp
quazipfile.cpp
quazipnewinfo.cpp
unzip.c
zip.c
crypt.h
ioapi.h
quazipdir.h
quazipfile.h
quazipfileinfo.h
quazip_global.h
quazip.h
quazipnewinfo.h
unzip.h
zip.h
```

**3.** Create an utility class for handling archives:

Header file:

```cpp
#ifndef ZIPPER_H_
#define ZIPPER_H_

#include <QObject>
#include <QDir>

#include "quazip.h"
#include "quazipfile.h"

class Zipper : public QObject {
        Q_OBJECT

public:
        Zipper() {}
        virtual ~Zipper() {}

        static bool extract(const QString & filePath, const QString & extDirPath, const QString & singleFileName = QString(""));
        static bool archive(const QString & filePath, const QDir & dir, const QString & comment = QString(""));

        Q_DISABLE_COPY(Zipper)
};
```

Source file:

```cpp
#include <QFile>
#include <QDir>
#include "Zipper.h"

bool Zipper::extract(const QString & filePath, const QString & extDirPath, const QString & singleFileName) {
        QuaZip zip(filePath);

        if (!zip.open(QuaZip::mdUnzip)) {
            qWarning("testRead(): zip.open(): %d", zip.getZipError());
            return false;
        }

        zip.setFileNameCodec("IBM866");

        qWarning("%d entries\n", zip.getEntriesCount());
        qWarning("Global comment: %s\n", zip.getComment().toLocal8Bit().constData());

        QuaZipFileInfo info;

        QuaZipFile file(&zip);

        QFile out;
        QString name;
        char c;
        for (bool more = zip.goToFirstFile(); more; more = zip.goToNextFile()) {

            if (!zip.getCurrentFileInfo(&info)) {
                qWarning("testRead(): getCurrentFileInfo(): %d\n", zip.getZipError());
                return false;
            }

            if (!singleFileName.isEmpty())
                if (!info.name.contains(singleFileName))
                    continue;

            if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
                qWarning("testRead(): file.open(): %d", file.getZipError());
                return false;
            }

            name = QString("%1/%2").arg(extDirPath).arg(file.getActualFileName());

            if (file.getZipError() != UNZ_OK) {
                qWarning("testRead(): file.getFileName(): %d", file.getZipError());
                return false;
            }

            //out.setFileName("out/" + name);
            qWarning ("using %s for output fileName", qPrintable(name));
            out.setFileName(name);

            // this will fail if "name" contains subdirectories, but we don't mind that
            out.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
            // Slow like hell (on GNU/Linux at least), but it is not my fault.
            // Not ZIP/UNZIP package's fault either.
            // The slowest thing here is out.putChar(c).
            while (file.getChar(&c)) out.putChar(c);

            out.close();

            if (file.getZipError() != UNZ_OK) {
                qWarning("testRead(): file.getFileName(): %d", file.getZipError());
                return false;
            }

            if (!file.atEnd()) {
                qWarning("testRead(): read all but not EOF");
                return false;
            }

            file.close();

            if (file.getZipError() != UNZ_OK) {
                qWarning("testRead(): file.close(): %d", file.getZipError());
                return false;
            }
        }

        zip.close();

        if (zip.getZipError() != UNZ_OK) {
            qWarning("testRead(): zip.close(): %d", zip.getZipError());
            return false;
        }

        return true;
}


bool Zipper::archive(const QString & filePath, const QDir & dir, const QString & comment) {

        QuaZip zip(filePath);
        zip.setFileNameCodec("IBM866");

        if (!zip.open(QuaZip::mdCreate)) {
            qDebug("testCreate(): zip.open(): %d", zip.getZipError());
            return false;
        }

        if (!dir.exists()) {
            qDebug("dir.exists(%s)=FALSE", qPrintable(dir.absolutePath()));
            return false;
        }

        QFile inFile;

        QStringList sl;
        // what's this ??
//      recurseAddDir(dir, sl);

        QFileInfoList files;
        foreach (QString fn, sl) files << QFileInfo(fn);

        QuaZipFile outFile(&zip);

        char c;
        foreach(QFileInfo fileInfo, files) {

            if (!fileInfo.isFile())
                continue;

            QString fileNameWithRelativePath = fileInfo.filePath().remove(0, dir.absolutePath().length() + 1);

            inFile.setFileName(fileInfo.filePath());

            if (!inFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
                qDebug("testCreate(): inFile.open(): %s", qPrintable(inFile.errorString()));
                return false;
            }

            if (!outFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly, QuaZipNewInfo(fileNameWithRelativePath, fileInfo.filePath()))) {
                qDebug("testCreate(): outFile.open(): %s", qPrintable(outFile.getZipError()));
                return false;
            }

            while (inFile.getChar(&c) && outFile.putChar(c));

            if (outFile.getZipError() != UNZ_OK) {
                qDebug("testCreate(): outFile.putChar(): %d", outFile.getZipError());
                return false;
            }

            outFile.close();

            if (outFile.getZipError() != UNZ_OK) {
                qDebug("testCreate(): outFile.close(): %d", outFile.getZipError());
                return false;
            }

            inFile.close();
        }

        if (!comment.isEmpty())
            zip.setComment(comment);

        zip.close();

        if (zip.getZipError() != 0) {
                qDebug("testCreate(): zip.close(): %d", zip.getZipError());
            return false;
        }

        return true;
}
```

**4.** Then use it in your project like that:

```cpp
bool rc = Zipper::extract(filePath, pathToUnpack);
qDebug("extracting %s", rc ? "success" : "failure");
```